# Covert Class Properties values in LowerCase with Typescript Decorator

Tags: typescript, typescript-decorator

I have a plain object I want whenever I assign this plainObject to class it convert specific values in lowercase.

Here is an example:

```
function lowerCase(target: any, propertyKey: string) {
  let value: string;
  const getter = function () {
    return value.toLowerCase();
  };
  const setter = function (newVal: string) {
    value = newVal.toLowerCase();
  };
  Object.defineProperty(target, propertyKey, {
    get: getter,
    set: setter,
  });
}

class User {
  @lowerCase
  username: string;

  email: string;
}

const plainObj = { username: "USERNAME", email: "example@gmail.com" };

const obj: User = plainObj;

console.log(obj);
```

This is not working please let me know how can I do that

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is to enable experimental support for decorators.

> To enable experimental support for decorators, you must enable the **experimentalDecorators** compiler option either on the command line or in your tsconfig.json:

**Command Line:**

```
 tsc --target ES5 --experimentalDecorators
```

**tsconfig.json:**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
  "target": "ES5",
  "experimentalDecorators": true
  }
}
```

Comment: `experimentalDecorators` is enabled and decorator is working but it did not work when you directly assign `plainObject` to a class object

Answer (score 0):

In your case you are just assigning an object reference. Also, you cannot use property decorators because

> a property decorator can only be used to observe that a property of a specific name has been declared for a class

[Read more](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#property-decorators)

Instead, method decorator can be used as below:

```
function lowercase() {
  return function (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
    
     var originalMethod = descriptor.value; 
      descriptor.value = function (...args: any[]): any {
          var that = this;
          const r = originalMethod.apply(that, args);   
          return r.toLowerCase()
      };
      return descriptor;
  };
}

class User {
  greeting: string;
  constructor(message: string) {
    this.greeting = message;
  }
 
  @lowercase()
  greet() {
    return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
  }
}


const u = new User('VVV')
console.log(u.greet())
```